# What Are the Smallest Totally Ordered Set and the Conditional Valuation Rule Needed for Intuitionistic Countermodels for Propositions in IPC?

Tags: intuitionistic-logic, decidability

According to [the Wikipedia article on Heyting algebras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra):

> Every totally ordered set that has a least element 0 and a greatest element 1 is a Heyting algebra (if viewed as a lattice). In this case p→q equals to 1 when p≤q, and q otherwise.

It gives an example of a ternary algebra that refutes the LEM, which appear generalizable to these equalities:

- `∀X(v(X) := lowercase(X))`
- `∀x(0≤x≤1)`
- `v(⊤) = 1`
- `v(⊥) = 0`
- `v(A∧B) = min(a, b)`
- `v(A∨B) = max(a, b)`
- `v(A→B) = cond(a≤b) := max(v(a≤b), b)`
- `v(¬A) = cond(a≤0) = v(a≤0)`

An intuitionistic countermodel for the LEM with a totally ordered set {0, .5, 1}, where `a = 0.5` is therefore:

1. `v(A∨¬A) = max(a, v(a≤0))`
2. `v(A∨¬A) = max(.5, v(.5≤0))`
3. `v(A∨¬A) = max(.5, 0)`
4. `v(A∨¬A) = 0.5`

However, if these rules are taken for `¬A∨¬¬A` under the same ordered set and value assignment for `a`, it returns:

1. `v(¬A∨¬¬A) = max(v(a≤0), v(v(a≤0)≤0))`
2. `v(¬A∨¬¬A) = max(v(.5≤0), v(v(.5≤0)≤0))`
3. `v(¬A∨¬¬A) = max(0, v(0≤0))`
4. `v(¬A∨¬¬A) = max(0, 1)`
5. `v(¬A∨¬¬A) = 1`

This version of the LEM is not an intuitionistic tautology, though.

At first blush, it looks like the smallest totally ordered set needs to contain intermediate values equal to the number of atomic WFF's in the proposition to have indeterminate values for each propositional variable:

`HA values := {0, .3̄, .6̄, 1}; a = 6̄; b = 3̄`

1. `v(((A→B)→A)→A) = cond(cond(cond(a≤b)≤a)≤a)`
2. `v(((A→B)→A)→A) = cond(cond(cond(6̄≤3̄)≤6̄)≤6̄)`
3. `v(((A→B)→A)→A) = cond(cond(3̄≤6̄)≤6̄)`
4. `v(((A→B)→A)→A) = cond(1≤.6̄)`
5. `v(((A→B)→A)→A) = 6̄`

However, I suspect that either that `cond()` is not generalizable as described if negation is defined as `cond(x≤0)` or that there's some caveat to negation that I'm overlooking.

Is my initial guess wrong or is my suspicion correct? If yes to either, is this procedure salvageable?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "this procedure", so let me just recall a few relevant facts instead. Intuitionistic logic is not complete with respect to any finite set of finite Heyting algebras. It is also not complete with respect to linearly ordered Heyting algebras, since $(A \to B) \vee (B \to A)$ is valid in each such Heyting algebra. The smallest example which shows that $\neg A \vee \neg \neg A$ (sometimes called the weak law of the excluded middle) fails in intuitionistic logic is the four-element Boolean algebra extended by an extra element at the top.

Comment: @Pilcrow, thank you, yes, part of the procedure (building the totally ordered set) allows for an arbitrary number of intermediate assignments given the number of atomic sentences.